# Does getUserMedia works in ionic-webview in IOS app?

Tags: ionic-framework, getusermedia

I'm using ionic 5 with capacitor and angular9.
All works on android and on the web.
But when i build the app on ios, I reveice an "**notallowederror**" at the line **navigation.getUsermedia**

```
 getMedia() {
    navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true }, (stream) => {
      this.handleSuccess(stream);
    }, (error) => {
      this.handleError(error);
    });
  }
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently ios 14.3 and 14.4 still does not allow getusermedia.
On the other hand there is an iosrtc cordova plugin which would allow to obtain the stream.
So do you know if I can use this cordova plugin in an ionic capacitor application?
And if yes how ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i can get the stream with the cordova-plugin-iosrtc.
I share a poc if that can help someone, it 's a integration with peerjs ans ionic capacitor.
https://github.com/iometrine/ionic-iosrtc-peerjs